# Flutter Getx Get.back() not returning value when used along with async function

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, flutter-getx

I am using Getx package and I want to return a value using Get.back(result: getPhoneNumber()). But Get.back() does not work if an async function is executed before it. Below is the code snippet where handleResponse() is an async function. In addition to this, I have added a print statement to check the value of isSuccessful variable. the value it returns is true.

[image]

handleResponse async function:

[image]

In addition to this, I would like to state that when I comment the ResponseHandler().handleResponse() function, it works fine as expected.

Comment: what is the return type of getPhoneNumber()? put getPhoneNumber() function to a variable then pass it to Get.Back();

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that the `back()` method seems to finish while `getPhoneNumber()` is yet to finish. The value passed in [return](https://pub.dev/documentation/get/latest/get_navigation_src_extension_navigation/GetNavigation/back.html) is nullable, and most likely gets a null value since getPhoneNumber() is yet to finish.

What you can do here is first fetch the value from getPhoneNumber() before calling `back()`.

```dart
var phoneNumber = await getPhoneNumber();
if(isSuccessful && phoneNumber != null){
  Get.back(result: phoneNumber);
}
```

Comment: When I used `Get.back(result: "something")` after await, it just back but not returning data (data is null).